# How can I can write javascript between two tags in HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, html, insert

I have a PHP file that inserts code into an HTML5 file. Something like this:

```
// this works fine
echo '<li>...something</li>';
// this doesn't work
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.write(\'<li>...something...</li>\');</script>';
```

If I "echo" these lines to the screen they both work OK (Of course, this is plain code!).
BUT this code above is "echo":ed into an HTML5 file and executed THERE. The first option works, while the second one doesn't (producing sometimes error 1561).

Example: http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp

Another example: http://www.modilo.net/dump.html

***Can anyone tell me how I can wrie javascript between two tags in HTML code??***

Comment: what's in BOO in javascript? `console.log(BOO)`. PHP and JS may cast some data types to boolean differently.

Comment: Forget the BOO. - Please take a look at the examples, especially the second one.

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript BOO isn't set, so you need to either set it in your echo like:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> var BOO = '. $BOO .'; // blah</script>';
```

Or, just put the value in, so it gets printed out to the user's browser:

```
... if( '. $BOO .' ) ...
```

Comment: Noop. "Lets say $BOO in PHP and BOO in javascript have the same value" so if I dump this to my screen both ways work, but they are dumped into an HTML file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'dumped into an HTML file'. If you are referring to when the output of your PHP script is sent to the browser, then indeed both of my ways will work. If you're referring to this code lying in a file.html on your server, and assuming your PHP is set up to parse .html files, then my ways will still work, because PHP will be executed.

Comment: I have an HTML file with a login. The login info is checked with a call to this PHP file. If the login is OK the PHP file dumps a new code between the <body> tags of the HTML5 file and calls the HTML5 file again. Everything works fine BUT the javscript.

Comment: Keep in mind that there is no file generated when a PHP script executes. The output is simply sent to the browser.

Comment: @user1013841: That's not how it works. ALL PHP execution is done before any HTML loads. Unless you're doing some kind of strange fopen() fwrite() shenanigans, then that output is going to the browser. In which case, the PHP will not be executed unless your html file is set up to be parsed as PHP. If you have an echo, then the output is going to the user's browser, period. (*unless you're messing with the output buffer, but you're probably not...)

Comment: The PHP works fine ... well except for that I can't get the PHP to produce the javascript ... or something goes wrong when I try to do it.

Comment: Once more: I have this simple login page where I call a PHP file to check the login info. If the login is OK the PHP file sets the cookie(s) and REWRITES EVERYTHING BETWEEN THE BODY OF THE HTML file (i.e. the main manu is shown). (If the user then looks at the source code he/she will only see the login form. Nice, huh?) When clicking on logout the cookies are deleted and the login code placed between the body tags of the HTML file. This works BEAUTIFULLY ... ... well ... if it wouldn't be that I need the PHP file to also generate JAVASCRIPT. THAT'S where I'm banging my head against the wall.

Comment: Similar to my case: www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp - getuser.php dumps its' HTML code into the HTML file between <div id="txtHint"> and </div>

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript to work, write down it in the appropriated tags.
Try the code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php // dump


// Lets say $BOO in PHP and BOO in javascript have the same value.
$BOO = true;
// Option 1 works fine:
if ( $BOO ) { echo '<li> PHP ... something ... </li>'; } else echo '<li> PHP ...     something else ... </li>';

// Option 2 doesn't work (and I need this!):
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
var BOO = '.$BOO.';
if (BOO) 
document.write(\'<li> JS... something ... </li>\') 
else 
document.write(\'<li> JS ... something else ... </li>\');';
echo '</script>';
?>
</head>
</html>
```

This code has the optput

## PHP ... something ...

## JS... something ...

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp The getuser.php dumps html code into the html file between <div id="txtHint"> and </div>. My case is similar. What I'm saying is that I CAN dump HTML code BUT NOT JAVASCRIPT and that I don't know why.