# Most efficient way to convert a javascript call to php (related to Wordpress infinite scroll/social buttons issue)

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, infinite-scroll

**Intro:** I'm a newbie on both php and Javascript and have been trying to solve [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212686/social-icons-not-working-with-infinite-scrolling-on-wordpress) for my site (another version of this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212686/social-icons-not-working-with-infinite-scrolling-on-wordpress)), but have had trouble putting into effect the answer by [LocalPCguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228429/localpcguy).
(in short: the issue is that with infinite scroll activated, the social buttons work on the first posts that are loaded, but do not work for posts loaded subsequently).

- I am working off of a WordPress them, and I've added my social buttons to an existing php file that generates most of the appearance of each post. I seem to be adding them to the right place because the buttons appear where I want them to on each post (only for the first ones on the page). Like the other two guys who posted about this problem, I am using [digg digg](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/digg-digg/) as my social plugin.
- Currently the code in the php file that generates the social buttons looks something like this:

  ```
  <div class="sharing-button">
      <?php dd_google1_generate('Compact (20px)') ?>                                                          
  </div>
  ```

Like I said, this makes the button appear for the first posts that are loaded, but once the infinite scroll tries to load additional posts, the social button will not appear on those posts.

For now I have tried the following:

- Add the code below just above or below (taken from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212686/social-icons-not-working-with-infinite-scrolling-on-wordpress)), or inside my `<div>` containing the buttons in the php file.

  ```
  if (typeof gapi !== "undefined") { gapi.plusone.go(); }
  ```
- That didn't work I figured it was because a .php file would need some kind of signal to know that it needs to run a javascript operation. So I looked around and found a couple suggestions on how to do this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898570/how-can-i-can-write-javascript-between-two-tags-in-html) and [here](http://www.frihost.com/forums/vt-109752.html). In neither case did I manage to get the buttons to appear appropriately. Below was what seemed like the least idiotic of those attempts:

  ```
  <?php
      echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
          if (typeof gapi !== "undefined") { gapi.plusone.go(); }';
      echo '</script>';
  ?>
  ```
- I also thought perhaps I needed to pass an argument into `gapi.plusone.go()`, and I tried passing my sharing-button `<div>` above, but that did not work either (php code inside a javascript script inside a php block... didn't have high hopes).

At this point I'm not sure what to do - I feel like the solution is probably quite simple but I'm completely stuck, having spent hours reading threads about javascript integration into php and the like.

Does anyone have an idea how I can go about applying [that Javascript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212686/social-icons-not-working-with-infinite-scrolling-on-wordpress) to my .php dependent Wordpress theme?

Many many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: this is not possible.

Long Answer:
FIRST comes PHP, SECOND comes javascript.
The PHP "program" is run at the Server, which is you web provider's server. This server works out all the PHP stuff. After this one is finished, the files of the Website are sent to your computer. It contains, among other stuff, javascript.

And this javascript is only run on YOUR computer, the one you're looking at. Once your Browser loaded the page and starts running javscript, it's already too late to ask the Server for some more info.

There are techniques allowing for that (AJAX is the Keyword), but that's another question :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to initiate the javascript of the buttons for them to work since infinite scroll loads the next set of posts using ajax. One example I found but it only does it for facebook if the plugin uses FBML:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    try{
        FB.XFBML.parse(); 
    }catch(ex){}
});
```

I'm using a custom implemented Like Box from facebook and infinite scroll and this works just fine.